# Holomorphic cyclic action on smooth toric manifold extends to C^* action?

Tags: kahler-manifolds, group-actions, toric-varieties

Let $Z_n$ be a homological trivial cyclic action on a smooth toric manifold compatible with the complex structure, the does it extends to a C^* action?

Answer (score 1):

Any cyclic group action that acts nontrivially on cohomology can't extend to a $\mathbb C^*$ action, because cohomology (with integer coefficients) is discrete so every continuous group acts trivially on it.

So the action of $\mathbb Z_n$ on $(\mathbb P^1)^n$ by permuting the $n$ factors is a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to exclude this case. What about adding a "homological trivial" assumption to the question?  Thank you!